# Positioning social networking buttons with CSS

Tags: css

I am creating a website using Bootstrap found here:

http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/wp/

My issue is that on the home page my social networking buttons for Twitter and Facebook found just underneath the `<header>` do not align horizontally if you look closely. I was hoping that by creating a separate CSS class `class="like-btn"` for the list item containing the facebook button I can make them align horizontally.

```
<div class="bs-docs-social">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="bs-docs-social-buttons">
      <li class="like-btn">
          <!--facebook like button-->
      </li>
      <li class="follow-btn">
          <!--twitter follow button-->
      </li>
      <li class="tweet-btn">
          <!--twitter tweet button-->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it looks like the facebook code for the like button is contained within an iframe which includes some CSS styles and unless my website happens to have the same matching protocol, domain and port as the Facebook iframe, I cannot not modify it because of Same Origin Policy.

I have noticed one CSS rule from facebook that if removed makes the buttons seem to align, but the border is removed from the bottom of the like button which is undesirable.

```
.pluginButtonSmall {
    padding: 0 5px 2px;
}
```

Is there anything I can add to my `.like-btn` class to resolve the issue so the buttons align horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Use `div`s instead of `ul`> `li` and the use `margin-top` or `padding-top` on the social container elements to make them align horizontally. Usually you need to move them one or two pixels since not all social buttons have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If that's causing the issue; maybe add a rule

```
.like-btn div {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

or

```
.like-btn .pluginButtonSmall {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try a css rule something like...

```
.like-btn, .follow-btn, .tweet-btn {
   float: left;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [getBootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com) they had this:

[image]

I used Chrome's developer's tools to see that the formatting came from this css file: http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css

It has a license at the top that allows me to use it.  So I downloaded it and made my own social media footer:

[image]

I found this thread because you are using the same class names as getBootstrap.com does, so I guess you are using bootstrap....